# I cannot login to wordpress dashboard locally even after changing database or config file. It just does not accept anything

Tags: wordpress, apache, phpmyadmin, wampserver

I had wordpress project files with me. I installed WAMP and copied the wordpress project files to the www folder.

I modified the wp-config file with the database file name, username and password. Now, I try to access http://localhost/my_wp_folder/, it does not ask me to enter wordpress details. Instead it takes me directly to my site first page. 
I try http://localhost/my_wp_folder/wp-login.php, comes up with a login page. I entered username and password from wp_users table, and it refuses to connect.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to edit the tabe wp_users and change the password. Try to connect again via: www.yourfolder.com/wp-admin

Comment: Learn your tool https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Comment: @DierigPatrick Actually I tried modifying the user created in the wp_users to my preferred username and password, but still it did not work. When I paid close attention to other table with the name mysite_users, I tried modifying the username and password in that table and tried to login and it worked. This was strange, as I didn't noticed that table first, as the normal instinct would be to change wp_users table. But thank you for your help.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thank you, its a useful link.

Answer (score 1):

try deleting the data base and recreating it, that will required wordpress to create the required tables, probably by doing that you will be asked for user and password.